the react background image changes depending on the components I would like to know how to do that
I'm learning and I saw the tomorrowland site and I would like to reproduce it, only on the home page there is this background scrolling effect which changes depending on the component I don't know how to code it and I need your help
import './App.css';
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="Blobs_blobs__cW0d3">
        <img src="/images/principal_bg.jpg" className="Blobs_backgroundImage__ciJQh Blobs_visible__EJ_Hc" alt="default background" />
        <img src="/images/bleu_bg.jpg" className="Blobs_backgroundImage__ciJQh" alt="Belgium background" />
        <img src="/images/blanc_bg.jpg" className="Blobs_backgroundImage__ciJQh" alt="Winter background" />
        <img src="/images/violet_bg.jpg" className="Blobs_backgroundImage__ciJQh" alt="Brasil background" />
        <img src="/images/rouge_bg.jpg" className="Blobs_backgroundImage__ciJQh" alt="Owr background" />
      </div>
      <div className='appContainer'>
        <Hero />
        <Hero />
        <Hero />
        <Hero />
        <Hero />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.

Set up a state to store the background color and set the state during different scroll positions.
Something like this:
Set your initial state. On the TL website its an orangy color so i'll use that
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('orange');

Have a 'scroll' event listener on mount and removes it on unmount to avoid memory leaks.
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);   // on mount

Then some function that checks scroll position and updates the backgroundColor state accordingly.
const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollPosition < 100) {
      setBgColor('white');
    } else if (scrollPosition < 200) {
      setBgColor('lightblue');
    } else if (scrollPosition < 300) {
      setBgColor('lightgreen');
    } else {
      setBgColor('lightcoral');
    }
};

All you have to do for your HTML div styling.
// Your container/background div wrapping whatevers inside.
<div style={{ height: '2000px', backgroundColor: backgroundColor }}>
    <div style={{ height: '200px', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
<div style={{ height: '200px', backgroundColor: backgroundColor }}>

Good luck.
